# echo without newline

Tags: echo

`-bash-4.1# cat output`
`"/root/mail/domain.com/root/Archive Dir.2012.04 April"`

`` for i in `cat output`; do echo "$i"; done ``
`"/root/mail/domain.com/root/Archive`
`Dir.2012.04`
`April"`

I want them on a single line, as they are originally stored in the file. Is it echo's fault?
`echo -n` will break everything, so it won't do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a while loop

```
while read i 
do
    echo $i
done < output
```

The reason why your command doesn't work as you expect is that `for` operates on words. The value of the $IFS variable determines what characters are used to delimit words, the default is `space`, `tab` and `newline`. As your input file contains lines that have spaces they are being spit into words. If you need to use a for loop you can work around this by wraping your lines in `"`

```
for i in "`cat output`"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: hmpf, same error when replacing echo with mkdir, in both for and while.

Comment: @w00t: Yes and it will be for exactly the same reason. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure it our yourself. This is all very basic stuff you should invest some time in learning the tools you're working with rather than blundering from one problem to the next. It'll save you lots of time in the long run.

Comment: it works with echo, why shouldn't it work with any other command? Again, it does the same even when using while

Answer (score 2):

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < output
```